# C programming file scope and block scope

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int f1(void);
int f2(void);
int f3(void);

int x = 10;

int main()
{
    int x =1;
    x+=f1() + f2() + f3() + f2();
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}

int f1()
{
    int x = 25;
    x++;
    return x;
}
int f2()
{
    static int x= 50; 
    x++; 
    return x;
}

int f3()
{
    x*=10; 
    return x;
}
```

Why f3 is taking global x variable? I mean main is calling f3 and In main we have x variable why doesn't f3 take the value of main x variable. Please help

Comment: Local variables override global variables, but only within that scope. Your confusion is a good indicator why you should *not* use local variables with the same name as global variables. It is a bad idea because it leads to bugs that are difficult to identify.

Comment: A variable inside a `{ }` scope is only accessible within that scope.

Answer (score 3):

C uses so-called *lexical* scope. That means that when you use a variable `x`, you look from the block where you are and outwards until you find the definition of `x`, and that, then, is the variable you are referring to.

In `f3()`, you have `x`, so you look in the block you are inside. There is no definition of `x` so you look outwards. In this case, outwards is the global scope, because we do not have any nested blocks here.

Lexical scope is not affected by which functions call which other functions. It is a static property of the code, not a dynamic property of the running code. If we used that kind of scope rule, it is called *dynamic scope*, the `x` in `f3()` would depend on who called it at any given time. So the `x` would be different at different times. There are not many languages that use dynamic scope any longer, because it is damned hard to figure out what variables refer to at any point in the program execution.

It is just different scope rules, and C uses lexical scope and not dynamic scope.

Comment: C does not have a global scope, which would make names visible throughout the entire program (including other translation units). It has file scope, in which names are visible from declaration through the end of the translation unit. (And external linkage is used to make them refer to the same entities as the same identifier in other units, but those other units need their own declarations because each declaration is limited to file scope; it is not global.)

Comment: True, but in the context of the question I found that a bit too technical.

Comment: Stringing students along wrong terminology or ideas engrains it deeper into their brains, making it harder to fix later. Even an answer that simply says what the correct terms are and uses them without precisely defining them is better than an answer that uses incorrect terms.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Because **scope** doesn't propagate through function calling.

Here are some blocks that illustrate scope.

```
scope1

main() {
    scope2
    function();
}

function() {
    scope3
    if () {
        scope4
    }
    scope5
}
```

`scope1` is a "global" scope, that is known and accessible everywhere in your project.  If you declare any variables here as "static" they are known only within that file.

`scope2` is known in the body of main(). The body of main() also knows and has access to `scope1`.

`scope3` is the same thing as `scope5`, and the body of function() also knows the global scope1. function() does NOT know `scope2`, despite being *called* from there. If you want `scope3` or `scope5` to know anything about `scope2` you must pass that as parameters to function().

`scope4` is the body of an `if`. The body of the if knows `scope3` and the global, `scope1`. Anything **declared** in scope4 is **lost** at the end of the block, so `scope5` does not know anything about `scope4`, unless `scope4` **actually changes** the value of a variable declared in `scope1` or `scope3`.

Confusion can easily arise when variables in different levels of nested scope have **the same name.**  This should be avoided!